# Avoiding repetition with <label>

Tags: forms, html, dry, code-duplication

When I'm coding a form I find myself doing some very repetitive typing.  For example, if I'm lining up a number of `<input>`s in a table, I might write

```
<tr>
  <td><label for="repeat">Repeat:</label></td>
  <td><input id="repeat" name="repeat"></td>
</tr>
```

where the third `"repeat"` is needed for GET/PUT form submission, the first and third are associated with each other, the third is for DOM access, and the second is for the (human) reader.

If I avoid lining up the various inputs the need for the first goes away:

```
<p><label>Repeat: <input id="repeat" name="repeat"></label></p>
```

but usually I'm asked to make them line up.

Generally, I think of duplications in code (DRY) as a bad thing, so even minor as this is I thought I'd ask to see if there was a better way.  As it stands, I have four opportunities for typos, three of which are user-facing and two which would cause programmatic issues if mistyped.

Answer (score 1):

How about lining up using CSS (width or something) and keep using your code instead of tables and tds.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do that, since I don't know _a priori_ what width the labels will need (or if they'll have to wrap, etc.).

Comment: @Charles: but how does hardcoding tables and labels resolve that problem?

Comment: @reinierpost: Tables automatically resize to fit their contents.  I don't know of a way to mimic that in CSS -- unless possibly by making a table in CSS, which doesn't seem like the right thing either.

Comment: @Charles: It depends on the constraints on the resizing.  The thing tables do that I don't know how to replicate with CSS is automatic alignment of both columns and rows without any other constraint on the height or width of cells.

Comment: @reinierpost: Right, that's my position as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously you are right about the wordiness of html, which doesn't always conform with the DRY-principle. And the next repetition comes in the server side code, that processes the form. But, as you put it correctly, each of these "repetitions" has its own meaning and could as well contain a different string.

Usually I try to take DRY to a higher level by not coding html forms by hand but using a web framework (in my case [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com)) which generates the html form automatically. That makes your question to a non-issue for me.

Comment: Actually I've finished the HTML for this project and am working on the server-side code; the additional duplications were what caused me to ask the question (in a sort of 'for next time' way).

Comment: Right, again let me repeat my plug for frameworks. HTML (and the other XML-like languages) in my eyes are not made for editing by hand. For composing the site, there is dreamweaver or kompozer (or construct it using reusable templates), and for the interactive parts there are the web frameworks. Have a look at [django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/), since I'm using this, HTML has become much easier for me.